# Graph API limit on friends / events returned

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following to get friends via my Android app

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, new EventsRequestListener());
```

I have been looking over the docs and cannot find any details about how many friends will be returned. Can I pass in a limit parameter such as 500? or this standard across all the api calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=5` or

```
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends?limit=5", params, new EventsRequestListener());
```

You can check your friends limit using Graph Explorer :

[Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools)

Click on **Graph API** , then add your query inside Edit Text and you should pass Access token into this , so Get Access token by clicking **GetAccess Token** Button. It will ask for option select **Friends Data Permission** , then you will get Access token then add your query to check your result.

Comment: @imran khan I have tried this. I am using the facebook android api from GitHub and the URL it sends is https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=5?access_token=XXX&format=json&fields=id%2Cname%2Cbirthday

Its adding the ?access_token after the URL

Comment: There is no need to pass access token with you query.. Just it needs active Access token

Comment: Its the FB android library that's passing in the access token to the query

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as the OP with the accepted answer. The way to get around the API adding the ? is to set the limit as one of your parameters.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("limit", "10");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, new EventsRequestListener()));
```

When it creates the URL it will add the "&limit=10" correctly after the access token

Answer (score 0):

yes you can pass limit by add ?limit=5 as :

```
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends?limit=5", params, new EventsRequestListener());
```

for more deatils see [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: i give answer first but why u not accpet my answer?